# Show that a function is monotonically decreasing

Tags: calculus, functions

How do I show that $\dfrac{\log(n^3+7n)}{\log(n)}$ is monotonically decreasing for $n \geq 4$?

I tried using induction but I'm stuck when trying to prove for $n+1$ since I can't simplify the expression whatsoever.

What's the simplest and most elegant way to show the result?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to rewrite the expression

$$\frac{\log (n^3 + 7n)}{\log n} = \frac{\log n^3 + \log \left(1+\frac{7}{n^2}\right)}{\log n} = 3 + \frac{\log \left(1+\frac{7}{n^2}\right)}{\log n}.$$

The numerator of the non-constant summand is easily seen to be positive and decreasing, the denominator positive and increasing.